# Set svg circle attr dynamically in react + jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, jsx

I have the following piece of code:

```
{items.map((item, index) => ( 
  <g className="item" key={index} >                
    <circle r="60" className="md" cx="5%" cy="50%"/>
    <text className="textNode" x="5%" y="50%">
      {item.text}
    </text>
  </g>
 ))}
```

where items is an array of objects. What i am trying to do is create an svg circle for each item in the array.

Right now all the circle are on one position. How can I increase the `cx` attribute of the circle in every iteration by 5%?

Comment: Hello I was curious if my suggestion below was able to help you get going in the right direction. Please keep me posted if you have any update on this.

Comment: @scniro it worked - thanks!! thats why i upvoted it :)

Comment: Thank you - please be sure to accept the answer as well (green check) if it worked well for you so we can both gain a little rep

Answer (score 1):

Why not just increment?

```
cx={`${5 * (index + 1)}%`}
```

should result in `cx="5%"`, `cx="10%"`, etc. Observe the following...

```
{items.map((item, index) => ( 
  <g className="item" key={index} >                
    <circle r="60" className="md" cx={`${5 * (index + 1)}%`} cy="50%"/>
    <text className="textNode" x="5%" y="50%">
      {item.text}
    </text>
  </g>
))}
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dtabdfn3/) - simple showcase of the transformation